# The installation of Workload Scheduler master component fails during the Prerequisite Check because the bc executable is missing on the system

Tags: installation, prerequisites, bc, workload-scheduler

The installation of the master component stops because the Prerequisite Check tool fails to run.

### Error message:

```
37 INFO  02:30.96 executePRScript(/tmp/IMC_01010000,prs.tws.script.cfg.unix): Enter. 
38 INFO  02:32.52 PRS command used for execution:echo IMC=IMC >> /tmp/IMC_01010000/
   codename.cfg&&chmod -R 755/tmp/IMC_01010000&&/tmp/IMC_01010000/prereq_checker.sh 
   IMC detail outputDir=/tmp/IMC_01010000
39 ERROR  02:32.53 PRS job is finished. Results are not available. 
40 WARNING  02:32.53 Error occurred while executing executePRScript.
```

Running manually the prereq_checker.sh I receive the following error message:

```
CTGPR2514E: Ensure that the binary for bc is available on the local system and is set
            in the PATH environment variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

The binary for bc is missing on your system. It must be installed before you run the Prerequisite Check.

```
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
```

For additional information, see: https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC2